# Load pdf fast which was made from photoshop cs6

Tags: pdf, compression, loading, photoshop, photoshop-cs5

I made my CV in adobe photoshop cs6 and saved it as pdf. But when I open the pdf, it is loading slowling and when I zoom in out zoom out in the file, the text gets blurred and takes some time to load to origianl quality. I tried compressing the pdf online (ilovepdf, smallpdf) but the results were still the same. Can anyone suggest me how should I save the psd file to pdf (settings) or suggest me any site which makes pdf load faster ?